# Criação de validação com o pattern

Tags: html5

Estou tentando criar uma mascara em um campo de formulário HTML para a matrícula funcional, entretanto não estou conseguindo. Estou usando a tag `pattern` do HTML5. No `input` coloquei a tag desse jeito, `pattern="[c]{1}+[0-9]{6}+$"`, e esperaria que o primeiro caractere fosse sempre um "c" seguidos de 6 caracteres numéricos (Formato da matrícula "C999999"). Já li diversos artigos e vi alguns modelos mais padronizados funcionando, o que estou fazendo de errado nesse exemplo?

Answer (score 1):

Bom nesse seu caso ocorre devido ao `c` da sua *pattern* ser minúsculo e o que você quer validar é `C` maiúsculo.

Para isso você precisa de um grupo de captura contendo a letra `c` insensitive case seguido de exatos 6 números.

Ficaria assim :

`[cC][\d]{6}`

[Teste](https://regex101.com/r/lzy2If/2)